# Map PHP named array to C# controller parameter

Tags: c#, php, rest, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a third party API with documentation for PHP, but I'm using C# and ASP.NET MVC.

One of API methods send as parameter `Fields`.

`FIELDS` is an array that contains field `ID` where int value is stored.

So in PHP it will be something like:

```
$fields=array(ID=>4);
```

What is the best way to get such a parameter to controller method in C#?

I'm doing it like this:

```
public class FieldsModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public string Test(FieldsModel[] FIELDS)
{
   //some code goes here
}
```

This code is working, but maybe there is a better solution to map PHP named array to a C# controller parameter?

P.S. Actually `FIELDS` array always contains only one ID if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to php arrays can be used as key,value data structure, when it is serialized to JSON you get something similar to:

```
{
  "ID": 4
}
```

The easiest way to manage it in C# (knowing that C# is mainly used to write Object Oriented code), is to parse that JSON into an object, that contains a property for each JSON key. You can also, change use fields instead of properties like this:

```
public class FieldsModel
{
    public int ID;
}
```

However the second approach isnt' recommended.

I think that you are only going to get a "Field", so you can rewrite your Test endpoint to wait for a single FieldsModel, like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public string Test(FieldsModel fields)
{
   //some code goes here
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I looking for. Thanks!